# How to parse XML with non-pair tags using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

All examples seen on the internet are XML files with structure like:

```
<open_tag>data that I want</close_tag>
```

but my XML file is different:

```
<Report xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="_x0034_00_x0020_-_x0020_Nomenklatury" xsi:schemaLocation="_x0034_00_x0020_-_x0020_Nomenklatury http://pcisrs/ReportServer?%2FTARIC%20Reporty%20Ciselnikov%2F400%20-%20Nomenklatury&rs%3AFormat=XML&rc%3ASchema=True" Name="400 - Nomenklatury">
<table1>
<Detail_Collection>
<Detail goods_nomenclature_item_id="0100000000" product_line="80" date_start="31.12.1971" quantity_indents="0" declarable_import="0" declarable_export="0" goods_nomenclature_item_description="ŽIVÉ ZVIERATÁ"/>
<Detail goods_nomenclature_item_id="0101000000" product_line="80" date_start="01.01.1972" quantity_indents="1" statistical_unit="NAR" declarable_import="0" declarable_export="0" goods_nomenclature_item_description="Živé kone, somáre, muly a mulice" parent_goods_nomenclature_item_id="0100000000" parent_product_line="80"/>

.....ETC....

</Detail_Collection>
</table1>
</Report>
```

If I understand the tutorials, this should work:

```
 subor = Nokogiri::XML(File.open('vendor/financnasprava/nomenklatury/recent.xml'))
    dataset = subor.xpath('//Detail')
```

but didn't.

Comment: It's because of those namespaces. You can do `subor.strip_namespaces!` I believe.

Comment: "but didn't". Can you be more specific? Did you get an error? Did you get nothing? Did `subor.errors` show anything? Your sample code needs to be runnable and demonstrate the problem. See "[ask]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with this data like in the example below. I removed the source path as I have not this data locally.

If i'm right and you are trying to the access Detail attributes:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

data_xml = <<-EOT
<Report xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="400 - Nomenklatury">
<table1>
<Detail_Collection>
<Detail goods_nomenclature_item_id="0100000000" product_line="80" date_start="31.12.1971" quantity_indents="0" declarable_import="0" declarable_export="0" goods_nomenclature_item_description="ŽIVÉ ZVIERATÁ"/>
<Detail goods_nomenclature_item_id="0101000000" product_line="80" date_start="01.01.1972" quantity_indents="1" statistical_unit="NAR" declarable_import="0" declarable_export="0" goods_nomenclature_item_description="Živé kone, somáre, muly a mulice" parent_goods_nomenclature_item_id="0100000000" parent_product_line="80"/>
</Detail_Collection>
</table1>
</Report>
EOT
subor = Nokogiri::XML(data_xml)
dataset = subor.xpath('//Detail_Collection/*')
details = dataset.map do |row|
  {
    product_line: row.attributes['product_line'].value,
    goods_nomenclature_item_id: row.attributes['goods_nomenclature_item_id'].value
  }
end

puts details

#=> {:product_line=>"80", :goods_nomenclature_item_id=>"0100000000"}
#=> {:product_line=>"80", :goods_nomenclature_item_id=>"0101000000"}
```